# Do vinyl doors and windows with a foam core promote mold growth?

Tags: doors, windows

I've had two companies give their sales pitch on vinyl windows and doors.  One has a foam core inside the vinyl frame, the other does not.  One says the foam core helps insulate, the other says the foam core promotes mold growth.

Who is right?  What are the pros and cons of a foam core in vinyl windows and doors?

Comment: This is not an answer because I don't have any sources and feel really knowlegable here but I have to imagine if moisture is getting in and growing mold inside the window frame it would do the exact same thing on the window that has no foam core. Sounds like FUD from the non-foam window maker to me.

Comment: I agree with auujay.  Mold needs food and moisture.  Foam is bad food.  Moisture shouldn't be getting in there anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to go the foam core route.  I think auujay's reasoning makes sense, and I figure the foam would be a better insulator than air.